# Run Time error 1004. Application defined or object defined error VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run this to develop a function for matrix multiplication which is similar to `SUMPRODUCT`. But I keep on getting the object defined error across `If Cells(a, b).Value = Null Then`

```
Sub Button1()
   Cells(2, 1).Value = MSumProd(1, 1, 1, 5)
End Sub

Function MSumProd(a As Integer, b As Integer, c As Integer, d As Integer)

Dim n As Integer
n = 0
Do While a >= 0
   n = n + Cells(a, b).Value * Cells(c, d).Value
   b = b + 1
   c = c + 1

   If Cells(a, b).Value = Null Then
      Exit Do
   End If
Loop

MSumProd = n

End Function
```

Comment: Try first to focus on the relevant sheet (e.g. `Sheets('Sheet1').Select`).

Comment: And, by the way, you need to check if `Cell(x,y).Value = ""` and not "Null".

Comment: The value of `a` doesn't change, giving you an infinite loop and cells can be empty but not `Null`

Comment: `If IsEmpty(Cells(a, b).value) Then`

Comment: Good catch @RowenChumacera. The undefined might come from exceeding the sheet's limits.

Comment: Thanks @TimWilkinson

Comment: Thank you for thanking me, but it is @TimWilkinson who made the real catch.

Answer (score 0):

In the `MSumProd Function` I am searching for the lastrow with data in column `b` (passed from your `Sub Button1`). Then, instead of using `Do While` and `Exit Do` , I am using a `For` loop from first Cell (`Cells(a, b)`) until last row with data.

**Warning**: In your code you are sending `Cells(2, 1).Value = MSumProd(1, 1, 1, 5)` , which means the second row in Column A will be overwritten with the result of the `MSumProd` function value. Since you are sending Cells(1, 1) as the start cell of the `MSumProd` function, and in case you have a few rows of data (starting from Cell A1, untill Cell A4 for instance), Cell A2 original value will be overwriten with the `MSumProd` value.

**Sub Button1 Code**

```
Sub Button1()

Cells(2, 1).Value = MSumProd(1, 1, 1, 5)

End Sub
```

**Function MSumProd Code**

```
Function MSumProd(a As Integer, b As Integer, c As Integer, d As Integer)

Dim n As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long, lRow As Long

' find last row with data in Column with passed integer 'b'
Lastrow = Range(Cells(a, b), Cells(a, b)).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

' reset SUMPRODUCT value
n = 0

' loop through all rows with data in column 'b'
For lRow = a To Lastrow
    n = n + Cells(lRow, b).Value * Cells(c, d).Value
    ' I think you are trying to advance the row (and not column)
    ' Therefore, you need to advance a and not b
    ' In this code I advance the row with lROw in the "For" loop
    c = c + 1 ' can be removed, since is advanced as with lRow
Next lRow

MSumProd = n

End Function
```

Comment: @Shashank Nathani  have you tested this code ? any feedbacks would be nice